# How do I Display First Name of User Once They have logged in?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using this code to retrieve the first name from my Firebase database and trying to display it in a label but it always returns the "Document does not exist in cache". My firebase security is set to read and write true. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

```
 func nameGreeting() -> String{
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid;(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid);
        let docRef = db.collection("users").document(userId)
        docRef.getDocument(source: .cache) { (document, error) in
          if let document = document {
             let name = document.get("firstname")
            print("Cached document data: \(String(describing: name))")
          } else {
            print("Document does not exist in cache")
            
          }
        }
        return ""
    }
```

Comment: "to retrieve the first name"  Nobody even knows your database structure.

Comment: I have a collection called users with a document for each user containing a UID, firstname and lastname

Answer (score 0):

you are using an async function (docRef.getDocument...) inside "nameGreeting", so you are returning "" before the firebase function is finished. Try something like this:

```
func nameGreeting(completion: @escaping ((String?) -> Void)) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let docRef = db.collection("users").document(userId)
    docRef.getDocument(source: .cache) { (document, error) in
        if let document = document {
            let name = document.get("firstname")
            print("Cached document data: \(String(describing: name))")
            completion(name)
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist in cache")
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
nameGreeting() { userName in
    print("----> userName: \(userName)")

}
```

Comment: It is still returning nil, and I used this exact code, is there anything else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I found out that my document's name was not actually the UserId and it was just a randomly generated string that was different from the userId. How should I fix this?

Comment: Here is my code for creating the user document. Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in if err != nil {self.showError("Error creating user")} else { let db = Firestore.firestore() db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["firstname":firstName, "lastname":lastName, "uid": result!.user.uid ]) { (error) in if error != nil {self.showError("Error saving user data")}

Comment: "...How should I fix this?" you have to make sure the id you use to create the user is the same value you use when you are making your document request. Also you should not use "!" in "result!.user.uid", whatever that is.

Comment: great. If my answer solve your issue, please mark it as correct, with the green tick mark, thank you.